# Import text into array in SAS data set

Tags: arrays, json, sas, dataset

I want to change my text from the form below (JSON) into a sas dataset.

```
[
  {
    "id":86374,
    "course":[
      "artificial intelligence",
      "data structure",
      "linear algebra"
     ]
   }
   {
    "id":12319,
    "course":[
      "data structure",
      "algorithm",
      "database",
      "linear algebra"
     ]
   }
...


]
```

Since the number of courses vary by ID, I don't know how to save all course names (maybe in array form) into sas dataset.

Comment: Please confirm what the corresponding output records layout should look like and the logic of how they're formed based on the input, You should be able to edit your question to add extra details.

Comment: How are you currently importing this data? Can we add to what you already have or are you starting from scratch?

Comment: Curious, is your data available in XML format?

Comment: @Amir I want output to be all courses are shown by each id. I want to use this data for figuring out such as "how many students take 'database' course".

Comment: @Reeza It's in json now. but i think it can be used in raw data format (if i just copy the text into text file). And we can add something on the data in line that does not change the result.

Comment: @Parfait maybe not. that's the format all i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Json file, it could be imported by proc groovy, here is data step. If it is unknown how many courses each student has taken, so temporary array is used, then transpose data to wide data for each ID.

```
filename myjson 'd:\json.txt';
data temp;
   array temp (100) $100. _temporary_;
   infile myjson lrecl=10000 truncover scanover ;
       input @'"id":' ID $10.;
       input;    
       do i=1 by 1 ;
       input temp(i) $100. ;
       if not anyalpha(temp(i)) then leave;
       end;
       id=compress(id,',');
       do j=1 by 1;
          var=compress(temp(j),',""');
          if not anyalpha(temp(j)) then leave;
          output;
       end;
       drop i j;
run;

proc transpose data=temp out=want(drop=_name_) prefix=Couse;
by id notsorted;
var var;
run;
```

Comment: Wow!!!!! It's what I exactly wanted!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
All of the datasets that gives me is useful to me!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using arrays for the initial import if you don't know how many courses any one ID might have, and just import the data in long format initially. That way, transposing it can be dealt with as a separate problem later on.

Here is an alternative approach for importing the data into long format that will work for any number of courses per ID:

```
data want;
infile cards scanover dlm=',' dsd;
input @'"id":' id;
do until(index(_INFILE_,']'));
    input @;
    if not(indexc(_INFILE_,'[]')) then do;
        input course :$100.;
        output;
    end;
    else input;
end;
cards;
[
  {
    "id":86374,
    "course":[
      "artificial intelligence",
      "data structure",
      "linear algebra"
     ]
   }
   {
    "id":12319,
    "course":[
      "data structure",
      "algorithm",
      "database",
      "linear algebra"
     ]
   }
]
;
run;
```

This assumes that none of the course names contain square bracket characters. You could allow for this possibility with some slightly more complex logic to check for square brackets at the start or end of a json line.

As this seems to be causing some confusion, here's how you need to modify this to use it:

```
filename myjson "/path/to/my/json/file.txt";

data want;
infile myjson scanover dlm=',' dsd;
input @'"id":' id;
do until(index(_INFILE_,']'));
    input @;
    if not(indexc(_INFILE_,'[]')) then do;
        input course :$100.;
        output;
    end;
    else input;
end;
run;
```

Comment: It says 'there is no 'datalines' or 'infile' statement.'
and '_INFILE_' variable is referenced but can't find datalines or infile statement.'
But I specified the infile statement as you told me so.

Comment: My answer is just an example using a `cards` statement within the same data step. To use this with your json file, you need to add a `filename` statement as per the other answer, change `infile cards...` to `infile myjson...`, and get rid of the `cards` section.

Comment: I've already tried with filename statement with cads and set infile name cards but it give the error above and the produced dataset has 0 observations.

Comment: Don't use a `set` statement - you aren't reading from an existing sas dataset. I've updated my answer again to make it clearer what I meant.